# PHP ini Question

Tags: php

In php.ini, the 'disable_functions' directive can be used to disable certain functions that you may consider to be not necessary or dangerous ones by putting them comma separated.

I just wanted to know, it it possible to set 'disable_functions' using php's function:

```
ini_set
```

For example, is following line of code correct?

```
ini_set('disable_functions', 'system, etc');
```

Thanks

Comment: FYI: PHP's safe mode is deprecated and removed in PHP 5.3 and PHP 6. http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php . You probably shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the following portion of code :

```
ini_set('disable_functions', 'system');
var_dump(system('echo "glop"'));
```

And the output :

```
glop
string 'glop' (length=4)
```

It doesn't seem to work ;-)

And, quoting the manual about [`disable_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) :

> **This directive must be set in php.ini**
>   For example, you cannot set this in
>   httpd.conf.

Which means you cannot change/set disabled functions using ini_set -- which seems logical : if you could change this at runtime, anyone could enable any additional function that was disabled bu the administrator for "security reasons", which would obviously not be quite secure...

Comment: huh, should have actually tried that first x.x  thanks